# What to do when a $3 \times 3$ matrix has only two distinct eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

$\newcommand{\Neg}{\phantom{-}}$When solving a system of equations:
$$
\frac{dX}{dt}= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \Neg0 & \Neg1\\
1 & -1 & \Neg0 \\
0 & \Neg0 & \Neg1
\end{bmatrix}X,
$$
I find the characteristic equation to be $(1-\lambda)^2(-1-\lambda)$.

Does this imply that the general solution is 
$X=(2)C_1K_1e^{\lambda_1t}+C_2K_2e^{\lambda_2t}$?
Or are there only two eigenvectors? Making the solution $X=C_1K_1e^{\lambda_1t}+C_2K_2e^{\lambda_2t}$?

Comment: You’ll need to determine the *geometric* multiplicity of the eigenvalues to know how to proceed.

Comment: @Gobabis: For this problem, you need to find a generalized eigenvector as discussed in the answer below.

Comment: Sorry but which text are you following to learn the subject? Even WA probably explains this at length...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda$, $\lambda$, and $\mu$.

- If $A$ has three linearly independent eigenvectors $K_{1}$, $K_{2}$, and $K_{3}$, the general solution of $X' = AX$ is
  $$
  X(t) = e^{\lambda t}(c_{1}K_{1} + c_{2}K_{2}) + c_{3} e^{\mu t}K_{3}.
  $$
- [Otherwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), there exist two linearly independent eigenvectors $K_{1}$ and $K_{3}$ of $A$ and a vector $K_{2}$ such that $AK_{2} = K_{1} + \lambda K_{2}$, and the general solution is
  $$
  X(t) = e^{\lambda t}\bigl[(c_{1} + c_{2}t)K_{1} + c_{2}K_{2}\bigr] + c_{3} e^{\mu t}K_{3}.
  $$